# phonegap: JQuery document.ready or Phonegap deviceready

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am creating phonegap app first time. I have below code which i used to fetch data from server. Problem is this code is working fine if i use document.ready.
But I read somewhere that i need to use deviceready for phonegap app.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'uid.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '&uid=' +uid,
        success: function(data) {

          alert(data.count);
});
});
```

I tried above code but it is not working. I mean ajax call not firing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'uid.php',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '&uid=' +uid,
            success: function(data) {

              alert(data.count);
    });
    });
```

Comment: What url you are using?

Comment: i am testing it in my mobile by using phonegap desktop. regarding the url mentioned in ajax. it is on localhost. I can confirmed that it is working fine.

Comment: deviceready even fired? If no, please be sure that you have added 'cordova.js' in your html file.

Comment: Cordova.js is loaded in head section.

Answer (score 0):

Use IP address of your computer instead of `localhost`.And make sure your mobile is also connected in the same network whatever you computer is connected.

**Sample code**:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://yourIpAddress/uid.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '&uid=' +uid,
        success: function(data) {

          alert(data.count);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did that as mentioned in the question. document.ready is working fine. I am getting issue with deviceready.

Comment: Welcome.I mean in case of `deviceready` you have to use `IP address`.I modify the answer.Check this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Welcome.Ok try this.